# How to add middle column to a dataframe with values taken from tags outside <table>?

Tags: python, pandas, tags

After many attempts i managed to scrape a dataframe from this [page](https://www.lefigaro.fr/sports/football/live/bundesliga/2020/2124890/dortmund-m-gladbach).
The code i used:

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.opera.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

errors = []
season = []

my_url = ('https://www.lefigaro.fr/sports/football/live/bundesliga/2020/2124890/dortmund-m-gladbach')
option = Options()
driver = webdriver.Opera(options=option)
option.headless = False
driver.get(my_url)
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(5)
        
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((
        By.XPATH,"//div[@id='appconsent']//iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((
        By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button.button__acceptAll'))).click()
sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.default_content()

#some scraping code here#

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
            By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='fig-tabs__list']//a[@id='tab_statistics']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
sleep(5)
dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
stats = pd.concat([dfs[5],dfs[4], dfs[1], dfs[2], dfs[7], dfs[12], dfs[16], dfs[17], dfs[22]])
print(stats)
Borussia Dortmund  ... Borussia Mönchengladbach
0                 9  ...                        4
0                 1  ...                        4
0                10  ...                        8
0                 4  ...                        2
0             47.6%  ...                    52.4%
0                 1  ...                        3
0             80.7%  ...                    81.4%
0                10  ...                       12
0                10  ...                        9
```

Unfortunately pandas doesn't extract the middle column with the statistics description
obviously because they are nested in dt tags and outside of the table.
Is there any way to extract those text values and add them to df as a middle column?
Kindly respect.
The html:

```
<div id="match-teamstats-attack-2">
  <dl>
    <dt>Buts</dt>
    <dd>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Borussia Dortmund</th>
            <th>Comparaison</th>
            <th>Borussia Mönchengladbach</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="stat-home"><span>3</span></td>
            <td><span style="width:99.8%;" class="home-percentage">100%</span><span style="width:0.10000000000000853%;" class="away-percentage">0%</span></td>
            <td class="stat-away"><span>0</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </dd>
```

To be more specific and as an answer to chitown88 this is the desired output.
Thank you for the interest.

```
Borussia Dortmund            Stats                 Borussia Mönchengladbach
       9         Tirs intérieur de la surface                 4
       1         Tirs extérieur de la surface                 4
      10                 Total tirs                           8
       4                 Tirs cadrés                          2
      47.6%              Possession (%)                      52.4%
       1                 Corners taken                        3
      80.7%      % de passes réussies dans le camp adverse   81.4%
      10                    Centres                          12
      10                 Fautes commises                      9
```

Comment: Welcome. please first read here first : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For your question if you use beatifulsoup you could extract data more easily.

Comment: so what is your expected output?